# Javascript question regarding the use of regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find a regex expression for a number 1 to 9, followed by trailing zeroes, followed by the end number 1 to 9. As like in a minesweeper game for clearing zeroes.

How do I match the part of an array where like i have 10009 or 2003 ? ,1to9 then zeroes, then 1to9?
How would I write it?

does this work?
updated: how do I ask this regex or another regex? the one i have below or a (trailing zeroes and 1-9)

```
(^[1-9][0+][1-9]$)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: How do I match the part of an array where like i have 10009 or 2003 ? ,1to9 then zeroes, then 1to9?

Answer (score 1):

### `[1-9][0]+[1-9]`

Move the `+` outside of the square brackets. Otherwise, it will match the literal character.

```js
const regex = new RegExp("[1-9][0]+[1-9]")

function test(testCase){
  console.log(regex.test(testCase))
}

test("10009")
test("2003")
```

To make the first digit optional, you can do:

### `[1-9]?[0]+[1-9]`

```js
const regex = new RegExp("[1-9]?[0]+[1-9]")

function test(testCase){
  console.log(regex.test(testCase))
}

test("0009")
test("2003")
```

Comment: You can use a [regex](https://regexr.com/) tool like this to test different regex as well.

Comment: would this work in an array with commas?

Comment: @macuser It probably will. What does the array look like?

Comment: I need to know how to ask two regex statements? this or that ^[1-9]0+[1-9]$ or that its trailing zeroes then a number?

Comment: @macuser You also want to match a number like `00005`?

Comment: yes but i'm using it on a random array that changes. How do I use this on any  array row?

Comment: @macuser I'm not sure what you mean by "array row". Can you post the code for the array? Also, I've updated my answer to make the first digit optional.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `[0+]` then you are saying that select any of either `0` or `+`

you want is quantifier `0+` which means `0 one or more times`

You can use `^[1-9]0+[1-9]$`

[image]

```js
const regex = /^[1-9]0+[1-9]$/;

function test(str) {
  return regex.test(str);
}

console.log(test("10009"));
console.log(test("2003"));
```